# Multi Find and Replace Html Code

Tags: linux, html, sed, find-and-replace

I have a URL error across multiple html files that I need to find and replace.

Currently my pages show:

```
src="//https:
```

and I need to find and replace all with:

```
src="https:
```

Does anyone know a way to do this on Linux?

Comment: Are you doing it over `ssh`? Why the tag?

Answer (score 1):

This sed command should do it:

```
sed -i -e 's/src="\/\/https:/src="https:/g' your_file
```

Simple test:

```
$ echo 'some text src="//https: some more text' | \
  sed -e 's/src="\/\/https:/src="https:/g'
some text src="https: some more text
```

Comment: Perfect mate, thanks!  that done it.  i had a typo in my syntax when i tried initially.

Comment: Doesn't this only work on one file at a time?

Comment: Yes. But I believe @CrisW will be able to tweek it for more files.

Comment: no. if you replace your_file with *.html it works across all html files

Comment: You need to use `-i -e`, otherwise you'll get backup files with `e` at the end (see the docs for `-i`). The `-e` is completely superfluous in this case, anyway. Otherwise +1.

Comment: @l0b0 thanks. I was aware of this problem, but was not sure about the correct solution (though I didn't think about it much).

Answer (score 1):

Searching for `replace multiple files [linux]` found several answers,
but I don't care much for them. Too much superfluous use of `cat`, `ls`
to get a list of filenames, and such. So I'll post a cleaner answer.

If they're all in the same directory, I would use a little script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir newdir
for i in *.html
do
    sed 's!src="//https:!src="https:!g' < "$i" > "newdir/$i"
done
```

And now the corrected files will all be in `newdir`. Note that non-html
files will not be copied over, so be careful. Use `diff -r` to compare
and check the results.

If you have a more complicated directory structure, simplest is to run
the script in each directory. If you only have a few, just do it
manually. If you have many, you'd want to use another script to traverse
the tree and call this one. I won't go into that here; if you need it,
post another question.

Edit: You could also use `-i` for in-place replacement as in Jakuje's
answer. I prefer a more cautious approach, myself.

Comment: You can use `-i.bak` to back up files which you are modifying without the whole temporary directory malarkey.

Comment: @l0b0: good point. But then it's harder to `diff` them all in one step.

Comment: No, because surely you use a version control system? At which point `-i` is kind of pointless anyway...